# c++  dll  using dllimport c#

Tags: c#, c++, dll, dllimport

I have a dll i wish to use in .net. I am trying to use dllimport but I am getting errors. I have put the dll in windows system32 folder and also where the exe is stored.the function definition I have been given that works in vb is.

```
        declare function LocalToWGS84 lib "TTDatum3.Dll"(Lat As Double, Lon As Double, ByVal Datum As Long) As Long
```

method sig

```
    #ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

int __stdcall WGS84ToLocal(double * lat, double * longt, int d);
```

c#

```
  class Program
{

    [DllImport("TTDatum3.Dll", EntryPoint="LocalToWGS84")]
    public static extern long LocalToWGS84([In,Out]double lat, [In,Out]double lon,[In,Out]long datum);

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(LocalToWGS84(50.82011492,-0.117981131, 150));

    }
}
```

the error is:

> Unhandled Exception: System.AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an idication that other memory is corrupt

Comment: Can you also put the signature of the method ? I mean the method signature in C++ ?

Comment: I dont have the method signature of the original code, i have been told it is written is delphi.

Comment: Remove the [In,Out] from parameters...

Comment: Hmm.. Try removing the [In, Out] pieces from the parameters. If those parameters are used as output parameters, try making them `out` parameters. If they're used for both input AND output, try making them `ref` parameters.

Comment: The function doesn't return a `long` or take a `long` as the last parameter. Unless VB is using 32-bit `long`s (.Net certainly doesn't), that could very well be breaking the stack.

Comment: public static extern int LocalToWGS84(ref double lat, ref double lon, int datum);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the lat and lon parameters are defined as pointers to int's (`int*`) in the C definition you need to mark the parameters as `ref`.  And the return value and the datum parameter should be an `int` and well:

```
 [DllImport("TTDatum3.Dll", EntryPoint="LocalToWGS84")]
 public static extern int LocalToWGS84([In,Out]ref double lat, [In,Out]ref double lon,[In,Out]int datum);
```

Answer (score 0):

Long in VB6 != Long in c#.net

Change Long to int

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, without knowing the method signature your stabbing in the dark a bit eh, look for a reflector / decompiler tool that supports delphi, you could try some of these to get the method signature; DeDe seems the business (not sure how old the post is) [Delphi Decompilers](http://delphi.about.com/od/devutilities/a/decompiling_3.htm)

You could try the MarshalAs attribute, but again theres a lot you could try. Without knowing the method signature it's very hit and miss.